# wix react native navigation v2 | unable to disable open gestures

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

In the RNN v1 we can use `disableOpenGesture: true`, but in v2 it doesn't work anymore. I tried the next but without success:

```
sideMenu: {
       right: {
            component: {
                    id: 'sideDrawer',
                    name: DRAWER,
                    options: {
                           disableOpenGesture: true,
                    }
                }
            },
        center: {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporal solution that fits my use case (I have a hamburger button which toggle the drawer):

```
export const openDrawer = () => {
    Navigation.mergeOptions('sideDrawer', {
        sideMenu: {
            right: {
                enabled: true,
                visible: true
            }
        }
    })
}

export const closeDrawer = () => {
    Navigation.mergeOptions('sideDrawer', {
        sideMenu: {
            right: {
                visible: false,
                enabled: false,
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Basically I disable the drawer completely when it's not shown. When disabled obviously gestures are disabled as well. Again this fits my use case and might not suite anyone.

**Edit**: it turned out my solution works on iOS only but also has this issue:
https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3837.
On Android it doesn't work at all.
I'm using "react-native": "0.56.0" and "react-native-navigation": "2.0.2485".